# Invalid Binary Architecture for App targeted for iOS 3.0 and armv6 / armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I have set my app to be distributed to minimum iOS 3.0 version and armv6 armv7.

Why is my app being rejected with Invalid Binary Architecture? It sounds like it meets the requriements.

> Dear Developer, We have discovered one or more issues with your recent
>   binary submission for "Charlotte". Before your app can be reviewed,
>   the following issues must be corrected:  Invalid Binary Architecture -
>   iOS 3.0 introduced support for multiple binary architectures. If your
>   binary is built for multiple architectures, your Info.plist must have
>   a MinimumOSVersion key with a value of at least 3.0. Additionally, if
>   your app is intended to support earlier iPhone and iPod touch models,
>   your app must contain at least an armv6 binary; "thin" armv7-only
>   binaries will not be accepted unless the armv7 required device
>   capability is also present in the Info.plist
>   UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key or the MinimumOSVersion key has a
>   value of 4.3 or higher.  For more information, see Technical Q&A
>   QA1707 at:
>   http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1707.html.  Once
>   these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and
>   click Ready to Upload Binary. Continue through the submission process
>   until the app status is Waiting for Upload and then use Application
>   Loader to upload the corrected binary.  Regards, The iTunes Store Team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "armv6" to Architecture by clicking on "+" and adding it as a new line instead of typing it along with the "Standard (armv6)" one. It worked and the submission was accepted.